# "buying stocks in large quantities" or "buying stocks in large quantity"?

Tags: grammar

What do we say if we buy 400 shares in IBM.

Do we say "I bought stocks in large quantities" or "I bought stocks in large quantity"?

ex:

> I bought stocks in large quantities, 400 from IBM to be more specific.

Also, why do I hear "buy a stock" instead of "buying stocks". Do they really mean buy 1 share of a company or buy several shares of a company? Because why would you buy only 1 share of one company in a single transaction when the transaction fee can be more than 10% of the share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stock is generally treated as a mass noun in the case of financial markets, so you wouldn't say "stocks" or "a stock" in this case, despite the general term "stocks and shares". "Share" is not a mass noun, so you would buy a share, or buy shares. But that's by the by.

The one time you would say "a stock" is to refer to the category of stock in question (a given class of shares in a company), to answer your secondary question.

"I bought stock in large quantities" is the more typical way to say it. But you wouldn't apply a number to "stock", as I said above, so your example sentence should read

> "I bought stock in large quantities, 400 shares in IBM to be more specific."

The alternative wouldn't be "large quantity", because then quantity is singular and it just doesn't work. You could say "a large quantity", which could be more natural in your case as you are saying you once bought a big chunk of stock. If it were "for example" rather than "to be more specific", "large quantities" works better.

For a third option, you can say "great quantity" without want the article in there, because then you're treating quantity as something that doesn't actually have quantity itself.